# How to save a particular value onto workspace from Matlab function?

Tags: matlab

I have an m file, which contains several files and I understand that when using functions, the variables used within those functions are not saved to the workspace in Matlab. All I need is to save one single variables within Matlab. What are the ways to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways you can save a variable in the base workspace, i.e. using [assignin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html?refresh=true)  or [setappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html?searchHighlight=setappdata) along with [getappdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html)

Let's create a dummy function to test it (do not name it assignin as it will cause trouble):

```
function Test_Assignin(~) %// Dummy function

clear
clc

A =rand(10);

assignin('base','AinWorkspace',A); %/ Assign the variable A (local to the function) to the variable named 'AinWorkspace' in the 'base' workspace, which you can access after running the function.

B = A/2; %// Generate other variable

setappdata(0,'B',B); %// use setappdata to make the variable available to the base workspace (hence the 0 at the beginning), and in your command window use getappdata. (See below).
end
```

And then if you want to access B in the workspace, you can use getappdata like so:

```
BinWorkspace = getappdata(0,'B') %// Use the same name as in the function/call to setappdata.
```

Note that setappdata/getappdata are quite useful when making GUIs in which you call external functions; it allows to easily share data between callbacks.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to declare that particular variable [global](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html):

```
function foo(k)
    var1=2*k;
    global var1;
end
```